# how to print first list element inside a list of lists in a for-loop structure?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to print the first list of a list of lists:

Here's my attempt:

1. I defined a function that splits a list into sub-lists inside a list.
2. Defined a initial list (`codes`)
3. Tried to print just the first list in `codes_chunks`, by using a for-loop structure.

```
########## define a split function ########

def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

########## splitting the list #############

countries = ['Spain', 'Portugal']
codes=['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7']

codes_chunks = list(chunks(codes, 2))
###########################################

# tried to print just for the first list #

for country in countries:
     for chunks_sample in codes_chunks[0]:
         for code in chunks_sample:
               print(code+'-'+country)
###########################################
```

Console Output:

```
# A-Spain
# 1-Spain
# A-Spain
# 2-Spain
# A-Portugal
# 1-Portugal
# A-Portugal
# 2-Portugal
```

Expected Output:

```
# A1-Spain
# A2-Spain
# A1-Portugal
# A2-Portugal
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for chunks_sample in codes_chunks[0]:
```

This line. Shouldn't it be `code_chunks` and not `code_chunks[0]` ? or `codes_chunks[0:2]`

My output with that change:

```
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A3-Spain
A4-Spain
A6-Spain
A7-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
A3-Portugal
A4-Portugal
A6-Portugal
A7-Portugal
```

with `codes_chunks[0:2]`

```
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A3-Spain
A4-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
A3-Portugal
A4-Portugal
```

`codes_chunks[0:1]`

```
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print `codes_chunks`:

```
print(codes_chunks) # [['A1', 'A2'], ['A3', 'A4'], ['A6', 'A7']]
```

Not you're selecting `code_cunks[0]` which is ['A1','A2'].

If you now iterate over this you'll get `A1` which is required but you're iterating again which results in `A` & `1`. So, you need to remove the extra loop.

Correct code for desired output:

```
########## define a split function ########

def chunks(lst, n):
    """Yield successive n-sized chunks from lst."""
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i:i + n]

########## splitting the list #############


countries = ['Spain', 'Portugal']
codes = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4', 'A6', 'A7']

codes_chunks = list(chunks(codes, 2))
###########################################

# tried to print just for the first list #

for country in countries:
    for chunks_sample in codes_chunks[0]:
        print(chunks_sample+'-'+country)
###########################################
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR:

Looping over `codes_chunks[0]` already provides the "code" `A1` and `A2`, thus your innermost loop is just one layer too deep.

### Step by step:

```py
>>> codes_chunks = list(chunks(codes, 2))
[['A1', 'A2'], ['A3', 'A4'], ['A6', 'A7']]
```

Thus, `codes_chunks[0]` in your second-order loop is only `['A1', 'A2']`.

```py
>>> for country in countries:
...     # code_chunks[0] = ['A1', 'A2']
...     for chunks_sample in codes_chunks[0]:
...         # you don't need another loop here
...         # chunks_sample = 'A1' or 'A2'
...         # `for code in chunks_sample` would loop over 'A1' yielding 'A' and '1'
...         print(chunks_sample+'-'+country)
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
```

---

### Generalization to more chunks

If you need to generalize your loops to all `codes_chunks`, you have two options:

Option 1: Wrap another for-loop around everything else, to alternate the countries in the output:

```py
>>> for codes_chunk in codes_chunks:
...    for country in countries:
...        for chunks_sample in codes_chunk:
...            print(chunks_sample+'-'+country)
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
A3-Spain
A4-Spain
A3-Portugal
A4-Portugal
A6-Spain
A7-Spain
A6-Portugal
A7-Portugal
```

Option 2: Add the same loop inside your outermost loop to complete countries one-by-one:

```py
>>> for country in countries:
...    for codes_chunk in codes_chunks:
...        for chunks_sample in codes_chunk:
...            print(chunks_sample+'-'+country)
A1-Spain
A2-Spain
A3-Spain
A4-Spain
A6-Spain
A7-Spain
A1-Portugal
A2-Portugal
A3-Portugal
A4-Portugal
A6-Portugal
A7-Portugal
```